# Dependent variables to get prometheus labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana

On my /metrics page I have strings similar to

```
 my_metric{controller="cont_a",action="act_a",le="1"} 5
 my_metric{controller="cont_a",action="act_b",le="1"} 4
 my_metric{controller="cont_b",action="act_c",le="1"} 3
 my_metric{controller="cont_b",action="act_d",le="1"} 2
```

On my Grafana dashboard I want to see two variables: `controller` and `action`. If I'll simply define them via queries like `label_values(controller)` and `label_values(action)`, they'll be independent, meaning that if controller`"cont_a"` is selected, all 4 actions will be available. 
But I want to make the action variable dependent from the controller variable, so, that if controller `"cont_a"` is selected, then only values `"act_a"` and `"act_b"` are available for action variable. And if`"cont_b"` is selected, then only `"act_c"` and `"act_d"`.
Is there any way to configure Grafana dashboard this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to have dependent variables in a Grafana dashboard. For example, let's say that on a variable `$instance` we have a list of instances coming from the `up` metric in Prometheus. We can set it up as a query with using the `label_values` function from Grafana:

```
label_values(up, instance)
```

Now if we were to have a second variable with a list of jobs that depends on the selected instance, we could use the following query.

```
label_values(up{instance=~"$instance"}, job)
```

In this case, we're using the already defined `$instance` variable to populate the options of the second variable (a list of jobs).

You can [see here](https://play.grafana.org/d/000000063/prometheus-templating?editview=templating&orgId=1) a working example of this approach.

Comment: Hi, Do you have a refreshed link of the example it is not showing anymore? Thanks